# Does the cleric get their holy weapon for free?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, cleric, pathfinder-beginner-box

Does the Cleric get their gods favoured weapon for free, or do they have to buy it when creating the character just like everyone else?

Comment: Note that a "[Holy weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/holy)" is a type of enchanted weapon. It doesn't have the same meaning as "deity's favoured weapon"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The gods favoured weapon has the folowing influence on a cleric:

1. A cleric gets proficiency with this type of weapon. I.e. if the cleric has quaterstaff as favoured weapon he can use any quaterstaff with no penalty.

> Clerics are also proficient with the favored weapon of their deity.

[link](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/classes/cleric.html#cleric)

2. The weapon summoned by a Spiritual Weapon spell takes the shape, critical threat and critical multiplier of the gods favoured weapon.

> The weapon takes the shape of a weapon favored by your deity or a weapon with some spiritual significance or symbolism to you (see below) and has the same threat range and critical multipliers as a real weapon of its form.

[link](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/spiritualWeapon.html#spiritual-weapon)

It grants no other benifits (if I'm missing nothing).

This means, **you don't get the weapon for free** and the weapon you buy is a normal weapon of its kind.

Comment: @doppelgreener Edited the answer.

Comment: I've cleared my comment away. Thanks. :) Have an updoot.

Answer (score 10):

They have to buy it like everyone else. They only gain proficiency with it and gain no other benefit.